# Blazor OnAfterRenderAsync Confusion

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I understand the idea of `OnAfterRenderAsyc()` but I don't understand how to implement what I want. I have `OnInitializedAsync()` that basically gets a summary information from files. After that I want to call 2 other methods and based on information returned from those 2 methods, I want to add some HTML into my component. So far, I have this:

```cs
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        driveFiles = await DriveService.GetList(true);
        permissionFiles = await DriveService.GetPermissions();

    }

    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
}
```

I then just want to add some basic HTML after `OnAfterRenderAsync()` has happened, something like this:

```cs
@foreach (var file in driveFiles.Select((value, index) => new {value, index}))
{
    <p>
        Name: @file.value.FileName
        <br />
        File Id: @file.value.FileId
        <br />
        File Number: @file.index 
    </p>
    <hr />
}
```

How do I do that? I can't find anything on Google that explains how to actually use `OnAfterRenderAsync()`, they just explain the basic ideas behind it. I'm sure I am overthinking it, but I can't figure it out

Comment: You just need to wrap the HTML part inside an if statement `@if (driveFiles != null) { ... }`

Comment: Ah wow how did I overlook something so simple. Thank you!

Comment: check the solution below which is a while neater, good luck :)

Comment: Use `is not null`, it is better semantics.

Comment: _"how to actually use OnAfterRenderAsync()"_ : use it for things that need the html to be rendered. Mostly JavaScript related. Use OnInitialized() or OnParametersSet() for loading data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When invoking asynchronous methods in `OnInitializedAsync` the UI will be rendered twice. Once when the first `await` is encountered and again when `OnInitializedAsync` completes. This enables the component to render mark-up for the user to see whilst it performs background tasks such as retrieving data from a server.

You can also see this behaviour in the following chart of the lifecycle of a blazor component (from microsoft documentation).

[image: lifecycle]

During the first render if you try to display your data you will get a null reference exception because the asynchronous task has not completed yet.

The solution is to wrap your ui code inside an if statement:

```
@if (driveFiles != null)
{
    @foreach (var file in driveFiles.Select((value, index) => new {value, index}))
    {
        <p>
            Name: @file.value.FileName
        <br />
            File Id: @file.value.FileId
        <br />
            File Number: @file.index 
        </p>
        <hr />
    }
}
else
{
    @* Show a loading indicator *@
    <p>Loading...</p>
}
```

For your scenario you actually don't need to use `OnAfterRenderAsync` method.

Sources:

1. [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0)
2. https://jonhilton.net/when-does-blazor-render-your-ui/
3. https://blazor-university.com/components/component-lifecycles/

Comment: Since the `OnInitializedAsync` is rendered twice, isn't this method not ideal for server calls since it will send the request twice?

Comment: `OnInitializedAsync` is called only once (unless prerendering is enabled but that's a different story). The UI is rendered twice (meaning the razor code will execute and generate html output that is rendered on the browser).