# Blazor, trouble displaying data fetched from api

Tags: c#, api, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

Im having trouble displaying my data from an api request, and I cant seem to figure out why. Here's my code so far:

This div

```
<div>
    <h4>Weather: @weatherData.location.name </h4>
</div>
```

Does not get updated when I have picked City, how come?

```
@page "/appweather"
<PageTitle>CheckWeather</PageTitle>
<h3>AppWeather</h3>
<div>
    <select @bind="SelectedCountry">
        <option value="">Select a city</option>
        <option value="London">London</option>
        <option value="Stockholm">Stockholm</option>
        <option value="Paris">Paris</option>
    </select>
    <button @onclick="GetWeather">Get Weather</button>
</div>
<div>
    <h4>Weather: @weatherData.location.name </h4>
</div>
@code {
    @using Newtonsoft.Json;
    private string SelectedCountry { get; set; }
    private Weather weatherData;
    private async Task GetWeather()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedCountry))
        {
            return;
        }
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync($"http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=key&q={SelectedCountry}&aqi=no");
        var jsonstring = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var weather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Weather>(jsonstring);
    }

    class Weather
    {
        public Location location { get; set; }
        public Current current { get; set; }
    }

    class Location
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string region { get; set; }
        public string country { get; set; }
        public string localtime { get; set; }
    }

    class Current
    {
        public double temp_c { get; set; }
        public double wind_kph { get; set; }
        public string wind_dir { get; set; }
     
    }
}
```

Kind regards

Comment: I don't see any line setting a value to `weatherData`. Should probably be `weatherData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Weather>(jsonstring);` instead of `var weather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Weather>(jsonstring);`

Comment: Then I get this error: `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'` on this line, `<h4>Weather: @weatherData.location.name </h4>` I know the string does not have any information while it starts running but it will once I have fetched the data. Why can it not run anyway?

Comment: This is because `@weatherData.location.name` is first called before your fetch has returned the data so `weatherData` is still null. You can either wrap the razor that uses `weatherData` in if statement like: `@if (weatherData != null) { ... <h4>@weatherData.location.name</h4> ... }` or initialize `weatherData` as: `private Weather weatherData = new();`.

Comment: Also check answers to [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74340365/net-6-blazor-server-api-call-deserialize-nested-json-objects-into-c-sharp-obj) and [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73451473/blazor-onafterrenderasync-confusion) for more information on why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

As there are several issues with your code, here's a simpler version that demonstrates how to make this work.

```cs
public class WeatherForecast
{
    public DateOnly Date { get; set; }
    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
    public string? Summary { get; set; }
    public string? Location { get; set; }   
    public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
}
```

The controller:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
    "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
};

    private static readonly string[] Locations = new[] { "London", "Stockholm", "Paris" };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{location?}")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get(string? location)
    {
        if (location == null)
            return WeatherForecasts;

        return WeatherForecasts.Where(x => x.Location == location);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
            return WeatherForecasts;
    }

    private IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> WeatherForecasts =
                Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
                {
                    Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
                    TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                    Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)],
                    Location = Locations[Random.Shared.Next(Locations.Length)]
                });
}
```

The `FetchData` page:

```cs
@page "/fetchdata"
@using SO75326593.Shared
@inject HttpClient Http

<PageTitle>Weather forecast</PageTitle>

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from the server.</p>

<select class="form-select" value="@location" @onchange=GetFilteredList>
    @if (location is null)
    {
        <option selected disabled value=""> -- Select a Location --</option>
    }
    <option value="London">London</option>
    <option value="Stockholm">Stockholm</option>
    <option value="Paris">Paris</option>
</select>

{
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Temp. (C)</th>
            <th>Temp. (F)</th>
            <th>Summary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var forecast in forecasts)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                <td>@forecast.Location</td>
                <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@code {
    private IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> forecasts = Enumerable.Empty<WeatherForecast>();

    private string? location;

    private async Task GetFilteredList(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        location = e.Value?.ToString();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(location))
        {
            var list = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>($"WeatherForecast/{location}");
            forecasts = list ?? Enumerable.Empty<WeatherForecast>();
        }
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var list = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("WeatherForecast");
        forecasts = list ?? Enumerable.Empty<WeatherForecast>();
    }
}
```